# Batch Normalization while Transfer Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, batch-normalization

I am currently transfer learning using the MobilenetV2 architecture. I have added several Dense layers on the top before my classification. Should I add `BatchNormalization` between these layers?

```
base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(200,200,3))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="Class_pool")(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(.4)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(.4)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(.4)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
X = Dense(20,activation='softmax')(x)
```

I have previously trained this network without any of these batch normalization layers and have struggled to get a good accuracy. I am only semi-successful after trying many combinations of learning rate and frozen layers. I am hoping this will help
Can too many `BatchNormalization` layers be bad for a network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch Normalization will help with covariance shift and as you are training on new data batch-wise, it would be a good thing for the network. There is nothing as too much BatchNormalization, just put after every layer that is having activations in it.